# SQL Query Generator for Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, orm, dapper

Hi was trying to find the ORM with the best performance to use in our new project. My final choice became Dapper. We also need to have our application to include the following features (at least) which prevent us from hard coding the SQL queries to pass to Dapper

1. Database independent
2. Run time entities definition

I thought about writing an SQL generator for Dapper but I am not sure the approach I am following is the best:

1. Declare an Interface with methods signature. The implementation corresponds to the Database system to be used (SQL Server/ MySQL/ PostgreSql/ DB2/ Oracle/ etc...).
2. Create Database XML Schema using the following format:

   ```
   <sqltable name="Foo">
       <sqlfield name="ID" primarykey="1" />
       <sqlfield name="Name" />
       <sqlfield name="Surname />
       <sqlfield name="etc" />
       <sqlreference name"KooID" table="Koo" field="ID" />
   </sqltable>
   ```
3. Generate classes/entities using the XML provided above (allowing the extension of the schema on runtime). Objects created are POCO.
4. Implement methods that loop on the properties of the current entity (using reflexion) and generate SQL statements where property is not null:

   ```
   String GetInsert(object currentEntity)
   return:
   "INSERT INTO Foo (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'BooBoo')"
   ```
5. The implementation will include at least

   ```
   SELECT
   INSERT INTO
   UPDATE
   DELETE
   JOIN /*(using references like the KooID above)*/
   WHERE /*(using filter expressions)*/
   ```

Can you think of any backwards/disadvantages of this approach? Can you recommend any improvements?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the contrib/rainbow parts of dapper, which are designed to provide automatic CRUD support (where dapper "core" is just query/exec) ? Also: if it doesn't have the features you need... it is entirely possible it isn't the right tool to choose. Also also: you are allowed to use more than one tool (maybe dapper for read-intensive display pages, and another ORM for data edit pages)

Comment: i'm going to go with the classic square peg round hole on this one. also, if you haven't looked at petapoco, it is neat, and comes with a poco generator to deal with classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using MEF instead of configurations

What if you'd dismiss all these configurations and just hard code these *providers* and use MEF to discover which one is included in your application and use that one? Then when you'd be connecting to a different DB you'd write a new provider and replace provider's assembly? MEF would then do the rest.

### Adding new entities duting production without recompilation

But as you added a few more details in the comments I would like to say that the way you're trying to do it is the way to go except I'd introduce a few changes:

1. Database provider discoverability could still be implemented using MEF so all you'd have to do is drop the provider assembly to your bin folder and your app would use that. This can of course be done by configuration as well. It's on you to decide how to instantiate correct provider.
2. Your example database schema seems to have syntax defined by yourself. Maybe rather use something that's already proven and allows standardised and likely also more complex definition.
3. Your UI (views or whatever you use) will actually be templates that can consume shcema XML and not POCOs. POCO objects will only *deliver* data to UI.
4. As you'll be using reflection extensivelly in your app it would likely slow it down considerably. I suggest you  use better (=faster) approaches. [Look at this library on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember) by Mark Gravell.

### Generating and cosuming design-time unknown entities

Data entities are going to be unknown during design time (from the perspective of compiled code) because those POCOs are to be generated from XML schema at runtime. Unless your application is purely database oriented (as in direct manipulation of tables in the database) I don't see how you'll consume these entities with hardcoded UI?

As you mention your UI will actually be able to read the same data schema UI and populate it based on POCO instances read from the database. That is all fine as long as it makes sense for your application to be purely data-oriented without additional business rules or user interface processes.

Comment: than you will lose the runtime entities definition feature. you cannot guess what would be the names the user will use to hard code them.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *runtime definition*? Does that mean you'd edit your entity configuration file and restart your application or would there be some other way of adding new entities?

Comment: I mean that in my application the user is able to define his own data object types (i.e. entities). I am willing to store each entity on a separate table and therefore just by extending the XML file with the new entities schema, the rest will be handled by the intended SQL generator.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: **1.** How do you suppose to create strong type POCOs during runtime? And use them as well? **2.** How do you expect those POCOs being consumed by existing UI that was done not knowing about these during desing time because they didn't exist yet? **3.** I think your plan is to not recompile your app when you add new entities, right?

Comment: 1. Using [Dynamic Source Code Generation and Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. The XML Schema will be consumed instead. It is easy to get the names and attributes from the XML schema and then use reflexion to control the POCO objects
3. No and yes. The end user will be adding entities not me and therefore I am trying to escape a new product version per client

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: Read my edited answer. If nothing else it provides some info how to avoid reflection for performance reasons.

Comment: Good point you raised about manipulating the entities with hardcoded UI. My current (step 1) need is almost data manipulation or data oriented application as you said. I will be using generic views and processes to handle the data and trigger events. I might have to come up with a solution soon to adapt the design. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

i propose my solution, in order to return the final text:

```
    createPROCEDURE [dbo].[Helper_CreatePocoFromTableName]    
    @tableName varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @codeLines table (lineId int, lineText varchar(4000))

insert into @codeLines
Select  rowNr = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by rowNr), PropertyColumn from (
    SELECT 1 as rowNr, 'public class ' + @tableName + ' {' as PropertyColumn
    UNION
    SELECT  rowNr =2 , 'public ' + a1.NewType + ' ' + a1.COLUMN_NAME + ' {get;set;}' as PropertyColumn
    -- ,* comment added so that i get copy pasteable output
     FROM 
    (
        /*using top because i'm putting an order by ordinal_position on it. 
        putting a top on it is the only way for a subquery to be ordered*/
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
        COLUMN_NAME,
        DATA_TYPE,
        IS_NULLABLE,
        CASE 
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' THEN 'string'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' THEN 'string' 
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'char' THEN 'string'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'nchar' THEN 'string'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'datetime' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'DateTime'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'datetime' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'smalldatetime' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'DateTime'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'datetime2' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'DateTime'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'smalldatetime' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'datetime2' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'int' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'int?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'int' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'int'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'smallint' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'Int16'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'smallint' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'Int16?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'decimal' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'decimal'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'decimal' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'decimal?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'numeric' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'decimal'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'numeric' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'decimal?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'money' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'decimal'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'money' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'decimal?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'bigint' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'long'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'bigint' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'long?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'tinyint' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'byte'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'tinyint' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'byte?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'char' THEN 'string'                       
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'timestamp' THEN 'byte[]'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'varbinary' THEN 'byte[]'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'bit' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'bool'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'bit' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 'bool?'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'xml' THEN 'string'
        END AS NewType
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName
        ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
        ) AS a1 
    UNION 
    SELECT 1000 as rowNr,  '} // class ' + @tableName
    ) as t Order By rowNr asc


declare @max int=(select max(lineId) from @codeLines)

-- assembly result 
declare @i int=1
declare @res nvarchar(max)=''

while(@i<=@max)
begin
  set @res = @res +(select lineText +'
  ' from @codeLines l where l.lineId=@i )

  set @i=@i+1
end

select classCode=@res
END
```